# Trouble reading unicode text from a JSON blob. How can this be done?

Tags: json, oracle, unicode, plsql, blob

I'm attempting to read JSON data from a blob variable.  I'm unable to read the data I store in the variable.  I was wondering if someone had an easy solution.

I am being passed a BLOB variable from a procedure (not shown here) and I need to read that JSON unicode data from that variable.

```
CREATE TABLE json_test
(
    step_no INTEGER,
    txt NVARCHAR2 (2000)
);

CREATE TABLE nchar_text
(
    txt NVARCHAR2 (2000)
);

INSERT INTO nchar_text (txt)
     VALUES ('Опасен за околната среда.');

COMMIT;

DECLARE
    lv_json_tx    BLOB;
    lv_value_tx   NVARCHAR2 (2000);
    lv_vu         NVARCHAR2 (2000);
BEGIN
    SELECT txt
      INTO lv_value_tx
      FROM nchar_text
     WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;

    INSERT INTO json_test
         VALUES (1, lv_value_tx);

    lv_json_tx   := UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw (n'{"text":"' || lv_value_tx || '"}');

    INSERT INTO json_test
        VALUES (2, UTL_RAW.cast_to_nvarchar2 (lv_json_tx));

    SELECT json_query (lv_json_tx FORMAT JSON, '$.text' WITH WRAPPER) AS text
      INTO lv_vu
      FROM DUAL;

    INSERT INTO json_test
         VALUES (3, lv_vu);
END;
/
```

What I'm getting back:

### STEP_NO TXT

1       Опасен за околната среда.
2       {"text":"Опасен за околната среда."}
3       ["¿¿¿¿¿¿ ¿¿ ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿ ¿¿¿¿¿."]

3 rows selected.

Comment: You are mixing character sets; `cast_to_raw` takes VARCHAR2, not NVARCHAR2. What are your database and national character sets, and what character set is sued in the construction of the BLOB you are being passed?

Comment: Thanks for the questions.  The database is 12.1.  NLS_CHARACTERSET = WE8MSWIN1252, NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = AL16UTF16.   The construction of the blob will use the db character set.

Comment: Are those Arabic characters supported in WE8MSWIN1252? I don't think so... so they can't be encoded in the DB character set. You could encode them in the national character set - your block would look *better* with a `n` before the text literal, `(n'{ "text":"تنطوي على خطرٍ بيئي."}')`; but you might still have difficultly displaying it (I'd expect 'text' to look OK, the rest question marks); and the BLOB you're really being passed would have to be UTF-16 too. Sounds like that isn't the case.

Comment: Adding the `n` should fix the raw conversion. To get `json_query` to work, you'll also want to change the end of that line to `'$.text' WITH WRAPPER` since you're matching a scalar.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to say why it would make it better... [`n'...'` makes it an nchar literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA), instead of a char literal - so it would align with `cast_to_nvarchar2`.

Comment: After a little digging I became aware that TOAD, my IDE, won't display that unicode text back via dbms_output.  So, if I insert the data into a table, I get a little further than I was.  I'm still unable to see the correct unicode text after the json_query.. mind blown.. I edited the orginal code block above to show what I'm trying.

Comment: I can't replicate in a UTF-8 DB; but I'm pretty sure the problem is that `json_query()` returns a VARCHAR2, not an NVARCHAR2. Also [see this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6253): "Conversion of input data to UTF-8 is a lossless operation, but conversion to output can result in information loss in the case of characters that cannot be represented in the output character set."